# How do you plot R formattable objects?

Tags: r

I have 3 tables of text/numbers that I'd like to plot vertically. They're defined just like this but named sequentially (pq2_plot and pq3_plot)

```
pq1_plot <- formattable(pq1_diffs, list(sla_diff = formatter("span", style = function(x) ifelse(x < 0 , "color:red", "color:green")),
                    bslc_diff = formatter("span", style = function(x) ifelse(x < 0 , "color:red", "color:green")),
                    sum17_diff = formatter("span", style = function(x) ifelse(x < 0 , "color:red", "color:green"))
                    )
            )
```

If it's not clear, the dataframe is just 4 columns. I've tried the following two methods with `pq1_plot` on top:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(pq1_plot)
plot(pq2_plot)
plot(pq3_plot)
```

also tried :

```
ggpubr::ggarrange(pq1_plot, pq2_plot, pq3_plot, 
                  heights = c(5, 9, 13), 
                  nrow = 3, 
                  align = "v")
```

I have a few plots from another script that used ggpubr so I wanted to give it a try. This one gives the following error: `Argument needs to be of class "ggplot", "gtable", "grob", "recordedplot", or a function that plots to an R graphicsdevice when called, but is a formattabledata.frame`

Picture of one of the tables:

[image]

And data for that respective table:

`structure(list(mean_2018 = c(4, 2.75, 3.87, 3.8, 3), sla_diff = c(0.18, 
-0.72, 0.14, 0.44, -0.58), bslc_diff = c(0.3, -0.69, 0.23, 0.49, 
-0.45), sum17_diff = c(0, -0.5, 0.48, 0.8, -0.33)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")`

So I'm able to plot the basic table, via this way:

```
pq1 <- tableGrob(pq1_plot)
pq2 <- tableGrob(pq2_plot)
pq3 <- tableGrob(pq1_plot)
grid.arrange(pq1, pq2, pq3, nrow=3, ncol=1)
```

But they overlap each other and don't have the conditional highlighting, which I'd need. If there's a way to do this, that would be optimal

Comment: Could you add sample plots to your question? That way one can think through the question before actually putting the code to work.

Comment: Sure, added in a picture. I plan on removing the headers from all the tables, or at least keep the one on top

Comment: Is this in shiny or a rmarkdown document?

Comment: Actually there seems to be no data in the question. I was referring to sample plots, please add data using `dput`.

Comment: Ah, added in the output of `dput`. @divibisan this is neither (I think). I'm using nothing special here